# How to display a loading screen until all the useEffect, and fetches are done?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I know how to display a loading screen for single api call or useeffect. But I have 5 components inside my home component. And I want to display a loading screen until all the useeffects in each components are loaded. And I'm making multiple api calls.

So, I can't make the loading screen disappear at one single component. If I do so, others will load late and it is visible for users.

How to handle this? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way - use global state. Like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).
But you also can create a parent state and callback like

```
const [loadedCount, setLoadedCount] = useState(0);
const handleLoaded = () => setLoadedCount(loadedCount+ 1);
```

Then, you pass the handleLoaded to child props and form there you fire it. When `loadedCount === 5`, all components will be loading. **But it's not good solution.** Better use global state.

Comment: Do you have any examples done with redux?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap them in a Promise.all.
Something like this

```js
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const firstCall = new Promise(() => console.log('foo'));
    const secondCall =new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(true);
        }, 5000);
    })
    const thirdCall = async () => await fetch(...) // async functions implicitly return a Promise
    const promises = [firstCall, secondCall];
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => setLoading(false));
```

Comment: How to use it in multiple components?

Comment: Are the API Requests handled inside each component? That would make the above implementation not possible of course, I assumed you called your APIs in one component and distributed the data to sub-components.
If you're trying to implement it that way you could, if you don't want to introduce more complexity by using Redux, track each loading state seperately in your main-component and change their state with a callback you pass to your child-components.
That would become sort of complicated too though.

Comment: This code seems wrong. It will (re)launch the promises *after every render of the component*.

Comment: @edemaine thanks I didn't think about that writing it down :)

Comment: @Braks I have a service component to handle api fetches. And reusing it in multiple components.